# Get values from label using jQuery

Tags: jquery, label

I want to get month and year value from label. How can i get these using jquery?

```
<label year="2010" month="6" id="current Month"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

Comment: you maybe don't want not to use custom attributes anyway, may break someday in some browser. ID's cannot have whitespaces.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think spaces for an id is valid.

So i'd change the id to not include spaces.

```
<label year="2010" month="6" id="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

then the jquery code is simple (keep in mind, its better to fetch the jquery object once and use over and over agian)

```
var label = $('#currentMonth');
var month = label.attr('month');
var year = label.attr('year');
var text = label.text();
```

Comment: Spaces for an ID not valid, yeah... well you're putting unknown attributes on a label; that's not valid either, is it? (I guess it's more accepted though...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`attr` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). For example, if you have a jQuery object called `label`, you could use this code:

```
console.log(label.attr("year")); // logs the year
console.log(label.attr("month")); // logs the month
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .attr

```
$("current_month").attr("month")
$("current_month").attr("year")
```

And change the labels id to

```
<label year="2010" month="6" id="current_month"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am changing your id to **current-month** (having no space)

```
alert($('#current-month').attr('month'));
alert($('#current-month').attr('year'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var label = $('#current_month');
var month = label.val('month');
var year = label.val('year');
var text = label.text();
alert(text);

<label year="2010" month="6" id="current_month"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var label = $('#currentMonth').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

While this question is rather old, and has been answered, I thought I'd take the time to offer a couple of options that are, as yet, not addressed in other answers.

Given the corrected HTML (camelCasing the `id` attribute-value) of:

```
<label year="2010" month="6" id="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

You could use regular expressions to extract the month-name, and year:

```
// gets the eleent with an id equal to 'currentMonth',
// retrieves its text-content,
// uses String.prototype.trim() to remove leading and trailing white-space:
var labelText = $('#currentMonth').text().trim(),
    // finds the sequence of one, or more, letters (a-z, inclusive)
    // at the start (^) of the string, and retrieves the first match from
    // the array returned by the match() method:
    month = labelText.match(/^[a-z]+/i)[0],
    // finds the sequence of numbers (\d) of length 2-4 ({2,4}) characters,
    // at the end ($) of the string:
    year = labelText.match(/\d{2,4}$/)[0];
```

```js
var labelText = $('#currentMonth').text().trim(),
    month = labelText.match(/^[a-z]+/i)[0],
    year = labelText.match(/\d{2,4}$/)[0];

console.log(month, year);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label year="2010" month="6" id="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

Rather than regular expressions, though, you could instead use custom `data-*` attributes (which work in HTML 4.x, despite being invalid under the doctype, but are valid under HTML 5):

```js
var label = $('#currentMonth'),
    month = label.data('month'),
    year = label.data('year');

console.log(month, year);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label data-year="2010" data-month="6" id="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

Note that this will output `6` (for the `data-month`), rather than `'June'` as in the previous example, though if you use an array to tie numbers to month-names, that can be solved easily:

```js
var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    label = $('#currentMonth'),
    month = monthNames[+label.data('month') - 1],
    year = label.data('year');

console.log(month, year);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label data-year="2010" data-month="6" id="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

Similarly, the above could be easily transcribed to the native DOM (in compliant browsers):

```js
var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    label = document.getElementById('currentMonth'),
    month = monthNames[+label.dataset.month - 1],
    year = label.dataset.year;

console.log(month, year);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label data-year="2010" data-month="6" id="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).
  - [Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).