# How to get <Label> text without using "id" element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch text embedded with <`Label>` tag. I have zero to very basic knowledge of Javascript and JQuery so I need guidance on this. I am trying this code which have copied from another stackoverflow post [get-values-from-label-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020962/get-values-from-label-using-jquery)

```
<label year="2010" month="6" id="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>

var label = $('#currentMonth');
var month = label.attr('month');
var year = label.attr('year');
var text = label.text();
```

The problem with this code is, as soon as I remove ID element it stops working. Please advise me, How can i get this working without ID element?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the id attribute? You can also use a class attribute for this: `class="currentMonth"`. And then your query for the label becomes: `var label=$('.currentMonth')`

Comment: Because ID element is not available in my working project for that specific label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class instead of `Id` to target the element

```js
var label = $('.currentMonth');
var month = label.attr('month');
var year = label.attr('year');
var text = label.text();

console.log(month,year,text)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label year="2010" month="6" class="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way of using pure JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<label year="2010" month="6" class="currentMonth"> June &nbsp;2010</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
let label = document.getElementsByClassName('currentMonth')[0];
let month = label.getAttribute('month');
let year = label.getAttribute('year');
let text = label.textContent;

console.log(month,year,text)
```

Answer (score 0):

At your disposal, you've got a string of methods to work with DOM. An easy way to get your element is using:

`document.getElementsByTagName("add-your-tag-label-in-this-case");`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp